# Realtime YOLO Object Detection using laptop webcam in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, yolo

I am using YOLOv3 and OpenCV for realtime object detection on my local system using a Webcam. Everything works like a charm and [here is the link](https://github.com/pdhruv93/YOLO-Object-Detection/blob/master/yolo-object-detection/ObjectDetector_YOLO_Webcam.py) of what I did for my local system(it uses `VideoStream` ).

I want to do the same on Google colab for faster FPS(my system is not giving high FPS). I read that Google Colab runs on some virtual environment and hence cannot access my local system webcam. But any suggestions if it is possible?

Comment: Do you want to send video stream to the Google colab and wait while it will be recognized? Hm. I doubt that will be faster.

Comment: @Nuzhny ..isnt there some direct way just like Google colab opens up my webcam and start detecting the object. Just like it works on my local system?

Comment: I would love to hear if you have some better or working approach.

Comment: Google colab execute code on server. You need create a public ip-address and translate video to the Google colab. It will be not fast and not simple

Comment: Check AlexeyAB repo for YoloV3. https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/2398 Somebody has trained yolo on google colab

Comment: @gameon67 I think he is doing the same thing which Nuzhny was telling. Using public IP camera. I would have to drill down to check implementation. But if you have some idea of specific code part, it would be easy for me to check.

Answer (score 1):

Google have provided a code snippet to do that by calling some JavaScript to access the webcam via the browser (`mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})`):

- https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi

It works well, and can be easily modified to remove the confirmation button if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the take photo function from google snippets mentioned in the above answer then registered a callback between python and the js function.
For the output used cv2_imshow.
Currently it takes 4 photos from the webcam and does object detection on it.
You can find the notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rGEAztA_FOn3mdb-l9DfZ7OQyb7jpgwQ?usp=sharing)