# How to use yolov3 on raspberry pi 4 with high performance

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, object-detection, yolo

I want to use yolov3 on raspberry pi 4 but it is too weak to run yolo, so are there any kind of solution to stream the webcam data online then process it with yolo and stream back to the laptop?
Thanks for answering me

Answer (score 1):

one way to solve this is to use colab and stream live data from webcam.

Link below show how to read data from webcam in colab -
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tbAeRge6KKgCYdC6ihDrsl80aRYoVOMa

we have many examples of object detection working with colab, one for quick reference is below - 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

Comment: This could be of some help for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886155/realtime-yolo-object-detection-using-laptop-webcam-in-google-colab